# The result of cons in "The Little Schemer"

Tags: lisp, scheme, cons, the-little-schemer

On page 178, there is a question: what is the value of

```
(cons rep-car
    (cons (cons rep-quote
        (cons
            (cons rep-a
                (cons rep-b
                    (cons rep-c
                        (quote ()))))
            (quote ())))
    (quote ())))
```

where

```
rep-car is car
rep-quote is quote
rep-a is a
rep-b is b
rep-c is c
```

The answer in the book is

```
(car (quote (a b c)))
```

But I think the answer should be

```
(car ((quote ((a b c)))))
```

Why am I wrong?

Comment: because `(cons X '())` is the same as `(list X)`, and `(cons X (list A B C))` is the same as `(list X A B C)`. So the expression simplifies to `(list CAR (list QUOTE (list A B C)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the answer in the book is right. Note that the expression has 3 occurrences of `(quote ())`, to create 3 lists. Then it conses various atoms onto the lists. Your answer contains 5 lists, not 3.

`(quote ())` simply returns an empty list. `(cons 1 (quote ()))` adds one item to the empty list to yield `(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(car ((quote ((a b c)))))
```

Try running that code snippet; you'll receive an error message.  What that code does is

1. Produce a list of the symbols **a**, **b** and **c**,
2. Attempts to execute that list as a function
3. Applies **car** to the result.

Since step 2 will fail (because **'(a b c)** is not a function), step 3 is never reached.

It should be clear from looking at the original code that no part of the code does that.

You probably meant to say

```
(car (quote ((a b c))))
```

which is wrong for the reasons given by Alex D.